# Find duplicates in excel workbook

Tags: excel, duplicates

I have a excel workbook that i want to find all duplicate rows across all the sheets and highlight them. Figured out how todo it in one sheet. Anyone that can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

it's only a starting point...

```
For b = 1 To Sheets.Count - 1
    For e = 1 To 9000
        yy = Sheets(b).Range("A" & e).Value
        If yy = "" Then Exit For
        For k = b + 1 To Sheets.Count
            For i = 1 To 9000
                If Sheets(k).Range("A" & i).Value = yy Then
                    Sheets(k).Range("A" & i).Interior.Color = 65500
                    Sheets(b).Range("A" & e).Interior.Color = 1265500
                End If
                If Sheets(k).Range("A" & i).Value = "" Then Exit For
            Next
        Next
    Next
Next
```

This function check between all the sheets, only the column "A" if there are no blanks. Set different color of the first occurrance and the others... If you have a big XLS or the searching criteria are more deeply (check all the cells of a sheets with AND OR NOT ...) the prg can use a lot of time...